# How to adapt android 4.x and 5.0 by use MediaBufferGroup class

Tags: android, c++

My libxx.so used MediaBufferGroup class,  compile and link under android 4.2 environment, run ok with android 4.x but failed wiht android 5.0.

logcat: dlopen("/data/app/org.cocos2dx.simplegame-1/lib/arm/libxx.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android16MediaBufferGroup14acquire_bufferEPPNS_11MediaBufferE" referenced by "libxx.so"...

The reason is acquire_buffer declaration difference between 4.x and 5.0.
Android 4.x
 status_t acquire_buffer(MediaBuffer **buffer);
http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/MediaBufferGroup.h
Android 5.0
status_t acquire_buffer(MediaBuffer **buffer, bool nonBlocking = false);
http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/MediaBufferGroup.h

I donot want to build two libxx.so, one for 4.x, another for 5.0.
The question is how to build libxx.so to adapt 4.x and 5.0? THX!

UPDATE:
add the source MediaBufferGroup.h and MediaBufferGroup.cpp (4.2_r1) to my libxx.so Android.mk. Run OK with 4.x and 5.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to build two versions of libxx.so, one for 4.x and the other for 5.0, but spin off as much functionality as possible into another .so file that doesn't link against native Android classes like `MediaBufferGroup` and can link against both versions. However, that requires rearchitecting your library, and also doesn't answer the question.

Another approach, that avoids building two versions of libxx.so is to create a wrapper class for `MediaBufferGroup` and compile it to two small .so files (one for 4.x and another for 5.0) and link libxx.so with the correct version at runtime, thereby avoiding having any linkage between libxx.so and `MediaBufferGroup` directly.

MediaBufferGroupWrapper.h:

```
#ifndef MEDIA_BUFFER_GROUP_WRAPPER_H_

#define MEDIA_BUFFER_GROUP_WRAPPER_H_

#include <media/stagefright/MediaBufferGroup.h>
#include <utils/Errors.h>

namespace android {

class MediaBufferGroupWrapper : public MediaBufferGroup {
public:
    MediaBufferGroupWrapper() {}
    ~MediaBufferGroupWrapper() {}

    status_t acquire_buffer(MediaBuffer **buffer);
};

}

#endif // MEDIA_BUFFER_GROUP_WRAPPER_H_
```

MediaBufferGroupWrapper.cpp:

```
#include "MediaBufferGroupWrapper.h"

namespace android
{

status_t MediaBufferGroupWrapper::acquire_buffer(MediaBuffer **buffer)
{
    return MediaBufferGroup::acquire_buffer(buffer);
}

}
```

Android.mk file for MediaBufferGroup wrapper library (4.x):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libmediabuffergroupwrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MediaBufferGroupWrapper.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidSource/JB4_2/system/core/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidSource/JB4_2/frameworks/av/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidSource/JB4_2/frameworks/native/include
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidLibs/JB4_2/system/lib/libstagefright.so
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

(change the `AndroidSource/JB4_2` and `AndroidLibs/JB4_2` paths to point to where you have the Jellybean source and Jellybean libs located)

Android.mk file for MediaBufferGroup wrapper library (5.0):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libmediabuffergroupwrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MediaBufferGroupWrapper.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidSource/L/system/core/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidSource/L/frameworks/av/include
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AndroidLibs/L/system/lib/libstagefright.so
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then change your code for `libxx.so` to use the wrapper instead of MediaBufferGroup directly:

```
// #include <media/stagefright/MediaBufferGroup.h>
#include "MediaBufferGroupWrapper.h"

// MediaBufferGroup mGroup;
MediaBufferGroupWrapper mGroup;
```

etc. And link against the wrapper in the make file for libxx.so. Add this at the top:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mediabuffergroupwrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libmediabuffergroupwrapper.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and then for when building libxx:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += mediabuffergroupwrapper
```

use the Jellybean version of the wrapper if you are continuing to link with the Jellybean libs. You can continue to link with the Jellybean version of libstagefright.so and it won't cause runtime link errors as long as you are not directly using any class (like `MediaBufferGroup`) that has changed.

Now you just have to link against the correct wrapper at run time. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to just put the two .so files into libs and then call the correct one with `System.loadLibrary("mediabuffergroupwrapper_lollipop")` or `System.load("lollipop/libmediabuffergroupwrapper.so")` and so on. The only way I've been able to get it to work was to save the two wrapper .so files in my project's raw folder as `libmediabuffergroupwrapper_jellybean.so` and `libmediabuffergroupwrapper_lollipop.so` and then copy the correct one to the app's data folder and then load it from there, like this:

```
String wrapperLibPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/libmediabuffergroupwrapper.so";
File wrapperLibPathFile = new File(wrapperLibPath);
if(!wrapperLibPathFile.exists())
{
    // copy the correct file from the raw folder to the path:
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource((android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) ?
            R.raw.libmediabuffergroupwrapper_lollipop : R.raw.libmediabuffergroupwrapper_jellybean);
    try {
        fileCopy(is, wrapperLibPathFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.load(wrapperLibPath);
System.loadLibrary("xx"); // load libxx.so, linking with the wrapper
```

where `filecopy` just copies the file like this:

```
public void fileCopy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

I've tested this out on a Nexus7 running 5.0.2, a Nexus 5 running 5.0 and an Optimus G Pro running 4.4.2 and it works. It's not really safe but if you are already linking against private APIs that can change under your feet then accepting that risk seems to be implied by the question already.

The two wrapper .so files compile to 21.7 Kb and 17.6 Kb for the Jellybean and Lollipop versions respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, add libmediabuffergroupwrapper_jellybean.so and libmediabuffergroupwrapper_lollipop.so can solve the problem. but for me,  just libxx.so, none other lib. I had update the question with my solution.